# When entering character ñ into a search, it retrieves all rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a simple search on my laravel project and when I enter the character 'ñ' into it and submit the search, all the rows from the table are retrieved.

The query is simple, it only uses one where: where('title','LIKE',"%$search_criteria%")

My DB is utf8_unicode_ci

Why is that happening??

Answer (score 0):

The utf8_general_ci collation is both case-insensitive and accent-insensitive, so your query returns all rows that do contain the letter 'n', upper or lower case, accentuated or not. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-effect.html for how collations do influence searches and comparisons.

You can change the collation for a given SQL statement by adding the 'COLLATION new_collation' at the end of the SQL statement. So this should work for you:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%ñ%' COLLATION utf8_bin;`

Comment: My collation is utf8_unicode_ci not utf8_general_ci.

In the other hand, it should be better to have my DB changed to the collation utf8_bin??

Comment: It is better to use a collation that makes sense for the ORDER BY clauses in your database, ie. utf8_general_ci, and change the collation on just a particular statement if you want an exact match. This way if you application displays lists they are ordered logically on screen for the end-user.